# How to modify files uploaded using django ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

Here I have a `ModelForm`, which (I was hoping) should replace any uploaded image with `/some/other/image.png`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)


class MyModelForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super().__init__(*a, **kw)
        self.fields['image'].validators = []

    def clean_image(self):
        img = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
        if not img:
            return img
        from PIL import Image
        i = Image.open('/some/other/image.png')
        fmt = i.format.lower()
        i.save(img.file, fmt)
        return img

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
```

I had expectations that whatever file object can be found in the `img.file`, later (when the model is saved) it will be flushed to HDD. However it didn't work as I expected as the original (uploaded) image is always flushed to HDD. How can I make it work as expected?

Comment: I think that to replace the image before hand you should try changing the file in the view's POST request. More specifically in the request.FILES you have the raw file code, that then you save/bind to your HDD. 

Try doing this code in your POST to see what your receiving: 

`for filename, file in request.FILES.iteritems():
    name = request.FILES[filename].name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before writing to the `img.file` it must be reset:

```
def clean_image(self):
    img = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
    if not img:
        return img
    from PIL import Image
    from io import BytesIO
    i = Image.open('/some/other/image.png')
    fmt = i.format.lower()
    img.file = BytesIO()
    i.save(img.file, fmt)
    return img
```